# Get the value of specific TextView in from a specific Row in a ListView. Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView`, each row in the ListView has three `TextViews`. When a row is clicked, it is highlighted. I would like to get the Text from a specific TextView in that row, specifically '`listview_row_employee_id`'.

How can I do that programatically?
Please see the both the XML ListView row layout and the Activity Java logic.

XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
    android:id="@+id/listview_row_employee_id"

    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
        android:id="@+id/listview_row_employee_first_name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
        android:id="@+id/listview_row_employee_last_name"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
private void instantiateListViewClickListener() {

    listview_employee.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            viewEmployeeDetailsButton.setEnabled(true);
            viewEmployeeDetailsButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#41ea12"));


            rowView = view;
            listViewPosition = position;
            //If there is a previously selected view in the list, it will be un-highlighted when
            //a new view within the list is selected.
            if (previouslySelectedView != null) {
                previouslySelectedView.setBackgroundColor(0);
                previouslySelectedView = view;
            } else {
                previouslySelectedView = view;
            }
            //Clicked view in list will be highlighted. Light blue
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66ccff"));
        }
    });
}


private void updateListView() {
    employeeList = dbDataAccess.getEmployeeList();

    Cursor cursor = dbDataAccess.getEmployeeListCursor();

    String[] columns = {
            DBOpenHelperEmployeeCenter.EMPLOYEES_COLUMN_ID,
            DBOpenHelperEmployeeCenter.EMPLOYEES_COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,
            DBOpenHelperEmployeeCenter.EMPLOYEES_COLUMN_LAST_NAME
    };


    int[] resourceIds = {
            R.id.listview_row_employee_id,
            R.id.listview_row_employee_first_name,
            R.id.listview_row_employee_last_name
    };


    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.employee_listview_row,
            cursor, columns, resourceIds, 0);



    listview_employee = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_employees);
    listview_employee.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onItemClick` method's 2nd parameter to get the `TextView`

This should work,

```
listview_employee.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        viewEmployeeDetailsButton.setEnabled(true);
        viewEmployeeDetailsButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#41ea12"));

        String empId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_row_employee_id)).getText().toString();

        //other logic
    }
});
```

Comment: Closing brace was missing, have edited my answer. Check now